# Software architecture components and connectors and UML 2 component diagram

Tags: architecture, uml

Recently I started learning Software architecture and it talks about **architecture components and connectors** and an **UML-2 diagram type is also called component diagrams**.

Could anyone tell the difference between those two or provide a link that does explain it?

Comment: Voting -1 because your question is ambiguous (what book exactly do you read?), not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and you did not show **any** research effort. You can learn more about component diagrams e.g. from http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide context as "architecture components and connectors" are ambiguous.  It can either be an informal way of saying "component diagram" or, alternatively, could be a generic reference to some other sort of informal diagram (blocks and lines, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

The example is a UML component diagram from Sparx Systems with various associations.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sparxsystems.com](http://www.sparxsystems.com/images/screenshots/uml2_tutorial/cd03.GIF))</sub>

The diagram above demonstrates some components and their inter-relationships. Assembly connectors "link" the provided interfaces supplied by "Product" and "Customer" to the required interfaces specified by "Order". A dependency relationship maps a customer's associated account details to the required interface; "Payment", indicated by "Order".
Components are similar in practice to package diagrams, as they define boundaries and are used to group elements into logical structures. The difference between package diagrams and component diagrams is that Component Diagrams offer a more semantically rich grouping mechanism. With component diagrams all of the model elements are private, whereas package diagrams only display public items.

Answer (score 1):

Architecture component is not defined in UML. It can be stereotyped Component for example. But, you can learn everything about UML from UML superstructure document.
See chapter Components.
You can download it from omg website for free. Here is a link: [UML Superstructure Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)